# Convert string base64 to string in C# without Encoding.UTF8.GetString

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, unity-game-engine, base64

I'm trying to convert string base64 to string in C# under Unity3d. When I try to build on Windows Phone 8, an error occurs because System.Text.Encoding is not supported yet.

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
string decodedString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Exception: Error: method `System.Text.Encoding System.Text.Encoding::get_ASCII()` doesn't exist in target framework

**Update:**

I tried an alternative of UTF8.GetString:

```
public static string byteArrayToString(byte[] byteArray)
{
    char[] chars = new char[byteArray.Length / sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArray, 0, chars, 0, byteArray.Length);
    return new string(chars);
}
```

It's supposed to convert bytes to string, like the UTF8.GetString, but all what I got is Chinese characters! I wonder if UTF8.GetString does something other than converting bytes to string.

Comment: have you referenced this site at all http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The base64 part seems to be irrelevant here. Are you *really* just asking how to convert a `byte[]` to a `string` using UTF-8 in Unity3D? Are you *positive* that `Encoding` isn't supported? (That would be very surprising to me...)

Comment: According to MSDN, `Encoding` is definitely supported in Windows 8, 8.1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, not supported in Unity3D, only when publishing to WP8.

Comment: @HamzehSoboh - I am not really sure what is the exact scenario but have you tried using BinaryFormatter (assuming objects are serializable with it)?

Comment: @Thinkster yes of course, it was my first choice for Android and iOS. But it didn't work for Windows Phone 8

Comment: @HamzehSoboh - Never knew that WP didn't support binaryserialization. Anyways it seems there is an alternative. Check out the protobuf-net project - https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/. Interestingly Marc Gravell who developed it seems to be a developer for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Thinkster Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it. but please note that not being supported for WP8 under unity that doesn't mean that WP8 doesn't support it. Thanks.

Comment: @HamzehSoboh - yes, there seems to be issues with that. May be falling back to a previous version might help if its something particular to the latest version of Unity3D. Anyways let us know if you were able to fix this issue.

Comment: I am behind a firewall and that has blocked access to all chat portals :|.

Comment: OK, no problem. I've updated my question. What I want to say is that any method for securing data will solve my problem. But I'm forbidden from using System.Text.Encoding or System.Security. Thanks.

Comment: How about  `BitConverter` class?